# How to acess NavHostController from nested composable Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Assume that my application looks like this

```
@Composable
fun AppNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController, startDestination = Route.Home.route) {
        /// other composes
        composable("Home") { HomeCompose(navController) }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeCompose(navController: NavHostController) {
    ChildCompose(navController)
}

@Composable
fun ChildCompose(navController: NavHostController) {
    navController.navigate("")
}
```

I want to access navController in nested composable to navigate
but I dont want to pass navController from parent composable to child compsable as above

Is there anyway to access navController from anywhere inside NavHost without passing it through composable hierarchy

Edit: for now, I can use CompositionLocalProvider to access navController in nested compose as below

```
val AppNavController = compositionLocalOf<NavHostController>() { error("NavHostController error") }

@Composable
fun AppNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        AppNavController provides navController
    ) {
        NavHost(navController, startDestination = Route.Home.route) {
            /// other composes
            composable("Home") { HomeCompose() }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HomeCompose() {
    ChildCompose()
}

@Composable
fun ChildCompose(navController: NavHostController) {
    val navController = AppNavController.current
    Column(modifier = Modifier.clickable {
        navController.navigate("Content")
    }) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [Testing Navigation Compose guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#testing) which specifically recommends *not* doing this?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I don't think passing data through compose hierarchy is good approach,  suppose that I have too many nested compose that need to use navController

Comment: in case there's no elegant way I have to use this approach for now

Comment: @cuongtd Did you read the link? Your ChildCompose composable should work independently from Navigation, then just use a lambda function.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes, I just read it

Comment: Nice trick, but unfortunely not useable in multimodule projects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With compose `1.0.0-beta04` and navigation `1.0.0-alpha10` as suggested by the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#testing)

- Pass lambdas that should be triggered by the composable to navigate, rather than the `NavController` itself.

```
    @Composable
    fun ChildCompose(
        navigateTo: () -> Unit
    ) {
        //...
        navigateTo
    }
```

and to use it:

```
ChildCompose(navigateTo = {
    navController.navigate("...")
})
```

In this way `ChildCompose` composable works independently from `Navigation`

Comment: what if we have many nested component and wanna use navigate on last child? we should pass it frequently?

Comment: I would recommend passing it around. But if it becomes too tedious then consider using a CompositionLocal.